# Converting String Array Back to an Array

Tags: php, arrays, string, parsing, extract

I'm creating an excel file with a bunch of different data points from information that I'm scraping off the web with Python.

One of those data points is a nested array, which is becoming a string when either it's inserted into the CSV file or read from the PHP file on my server.

The whole idea behind using the nested array is so that I can insert each pair of images and thumbnails into their respective columns in a single row on a separate MySQL table.

**Nested Array**

```
images_and_thumbnails = [
  ['https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/615JCt72MXL._UY575_.jpg', 'https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/41rExpVS75L._US40_.jpg'],
  ['https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/71Ss5tJW-4L._UY575_.jpg', 'https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/41RpAwvZJ5L._US40_.jpg'],
  ['https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/6157znz2BeL._UY575_.jpg', 'https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/41mSje9rDSL._US40_.jpg'],
  ['https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/815wlLde-gL._UY575_.jpg', 'https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/51jty5d4BpL._US40_.jpg'],
  ['https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/71D2gVlCUOL._UY575_.jpg', 'https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/41kCBJYI%2BCL._US40_.jpg'],
  ['https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/71EfsMWdx0L._UY575_.jpg', 'https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/41utl4%2B%2B%2BoL._US40_.jpg'],
  ['https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/61m4mFpIvVL._UY575_.jpg', 'https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/41S27BGn0UL._US40_.jpg']
]
```

**PHP Script to Process the Excel File**

```
$str2 = 'INSERT INTO deals_images_and_thumbnails (asin, image, thumbnail) VALUES (:asin, :image, :thumbnail)';
$sta2 = $conn->prepare($str2);

$file = fopen($_SESSION['file'], 'r');

while (!feof($file)) {
  while($row = fgetcsv($file)) {
    if (count($row) === 31) {

      $images_and_thumbnails = $row[8];

      foreach ($images_and_thumbnails as $value) {
        $sta2->execute([
          'asin' => $asin,
          'image' => $value[0],
          'thumbnail' => $value[1]
        ]);
      }
```

The issue is that `$images_and_thumbnails` is a string, which is obviously "an invalid argument" for the `foreach` loop.

Is there any way to convert the string back to an array?

Will simply removing the double quotes do the job?

Comment: instead of overriding `images_and_thumbnails` just create a new variable name for `$images_and_thumbnails = $row[8];`

Comment: @Beginner what do u mean "instead of overwriting it"? where am i overwriting it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the format of `$images_and_thumbnails` is fixed, you could use [`explode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) to split it up:

```
$images_and_thumbnails = "[
  ['https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/615JCt72MXL._UY575_.jpg', 'https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/41rExpVS75L._US40_.jpg'],
  ['https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/71Ss5tJW-4L._UY575_.jpg', 'https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/41RpAwvZJ5L._US40_.jpg'],
  ['https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/6157znz2BeL._UY575_.jpg', 'https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/41mSje9rDSL._US40_.jpg'],
  ['https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/815wlLde-gL._UY575_.jpg', 'https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/51jty5d4BpL._US40_.jpg'],
  ['https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/71D2gVlCUOL._UY575_.jpg', 'https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/41kCBJYI%2BCL._US40_.jpg'],
  ['https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/71EfsMWdx0L._UY575_.jpg', 'https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/41utl4%2B%2B%2BoL._US40_.jpg'],
  ['https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/61m4mFpIvVL._UY575_.jpg', 'https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/41S27BGn0UL._US40_.jpg']
]";
foreach (explode('],', $images_and_thumbnails) as $i_and_t) {
    $value = explode("', '", trim($i_and_t, "[]' \t\r\n"));
    print_r($value);
}
```

However if it can be variable with spacing, it is better to use [`preg_split`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-split.php):

```
foreach (preg_split('/\'\s*\]\s*,\s*\[\s*\'/', $images_and_thumbnails) as $i_and_t) {
    $value = preg_split('/\'\s*,\s*\'/', trim($i_and_t, "[]' \t\r\n"));
    print_r($value);
}
```

If you're **100% certain** that the data is safe, you could also [`eval`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.eval.php) it i.e.

```
eval ("\$images_and_thumbnails = [
  ['https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/615JCt72MXL._UY575_.jpg', 'https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/41rExpVS75L._US40_.jpg'],
  ['https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/71Ss5tJW-4L._UY575_.jpg', 'https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/41RpAwvZJ5L._US40_.jpg'],
  ['https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/6157znz2BeL._UY575_.jpg', 'https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/41mSje9rDSL._US40_.jpg'],
  ['https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/815wlLde-gL._UY575_.jpg', 'https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/51jty5d4BpL._US40_.jpg'],
  ['https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/71D2gVlCUOL._UY575_.jpg', 'https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/41kCBJYI%2BCL._US40_.jpg'],
  ['https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/71EfsMWdx0L._UY575_.jpg', 'https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/41utl4%2B%2B%2BoL._US40_.jpg'],
  ['https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/61m4mFpIvVL._UY575_.jpg', 'https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/41S27BGn0UL._US40_.jpg']
];");
print_r($images_and_thumbnails);
```

Any of those methods will give you the same result:

```
Array ( 
    [0] => https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/615JCt72MXL._UY575_.jpg
    [1] => https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/41rExpVS75L._US40_.jpg 
)
Array (
    [0] => https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/71Ss5tJW-4L._UY575_.jpg
    [1] => https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/41RpAwvZJ5L._US40_.jpg 
)
Array (
    [0] => https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/6157znz2BeL._UY575_.jpg
    [1] => https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/41mSje9rDSL._US40_.jpg 
)
Array (
    [0] => https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/815wlLde-gL._UY575_.jpg
    [1] => https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/51jty5d4BpL._US40_.jpg 
)
Array (
    [0] => https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/71D2gVlCUOL._UY575_.jpg
    [1] => https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/41kCBJYI%2BCL._US40_.jpg 
)
Array (
    [0] => https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/71EfsMWdx0L._UY575_.jpg
    [1] => https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/41utl4%2B%2B%2BoL._US40_.jpg
)
Array ( 
    [0] => https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/61m4mFpIvVL._UY575_.jpg
    [1] => https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/41S27BGn0UL._US40_.jpg 
)
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/CXS8K)

Comment: i just had basically the same idea while i was in the shower. there is no simpler way to do it other than exploding it?

Comment: You could `eval` it but that is a last resort; this is the easiest solution I can think of without eval. Leave the question open a while and you might get some better ideas.

Comment: thanks buddy appreciate it! if nothing else comes in, ill mark this as the sol

Comment: i think im prolly gon mark this as the answer. it's pretty simple. just an extra `foreach` loop with the `explode`. im super new to a lot of these languages and didnt realize u could `trim` more than whitespace. anyways ur solution works like a charm!

Comment: hey what is 3v4l.org exactly? can i test php scripts on there?

Comment: Yeah 3v4l.org is a place for testing PHP. There's also rextester.com which allows testing PHP and MySQL and javascript and all sorts of other languages. I use them all a lot.

Comment: You don't have a `;` to terminate the line (what you pass to `eval` has to be valid PHP code). But you also need an assignment in the string otherwise it won't actually do anything. Take a look at the eval code I put in my answer.

Comment: Did you add the assignment string i.e. `"\$images_and_thumbnails = "` at the beginning as in my example?

Comment: Minus the quotes but you absolutely need the backslash otherwise PHP will try to substitute the value of `$images_and_thumbnails` instead of passing the string `$images_and_thumbnails` to `eval`

Comment: still doesn't work with a backslash. and what do u mean by it will substitute the value of `$images_and_thumbnails` for something other than a string if variables aren't escaped?

Comment: Try this: `$x = 4; echo "\$x = $x";` output is `"$x = 4"`. The \ prevents `$x` at the start of the string being substituted with its value.

Comment: ohhh thats why i was getting confused. `$images_and_thumbnails` is not part of the string, but just the variable to which i assigned the string array

Answer (score 1):

As single call of `preg_match_all()` with the PREG_SET_ORDER flag will set up a multidimensional array that will make isolating your desired data a snap.  Furthermore, if you wanted to perform validation on the input data, you could write a more strict pattern to ensure you are getting valid jpg strings.

If this was my task and I had no control over the format of the input data, this is how I would parse it.  One call does it all.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/lndAT)) ([Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/pJyEe1/2))

```
$string = <<<STRING
images_and_thumbnails = [
  ['https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/615JCt72MXL._UY575_.jpg', 'https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/41rExpVS75L._US40_.jpg'],
  ['https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/71Ss5tJW-4L._UY575_.jpg', 'https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/41RpAwvZJ5L._US40_.jpg'],
  ['https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/6157znz2BeL._UY575_.jpg', 'https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/41mSje9rDSL._US40_.jpg'],
  ['https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/815wlLde-gL._UY575_.jpg', 'https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/51jty5d4BpL._US40_.jpg'],
  ['https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/71D2gVlCUOL._UY575_.jpg', 'https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/41kCBJYI%2BCL._US40_.jpg'],
  ['https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/71EfsMWdx0L._UY575_.jpg', 'https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/41utl4%2B%2B%2BoL._US40_.jpg'],
  ['https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/61m4mFpIvVL._UY575_.jpg', 'https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/41S27BGn0UL._US40_.jpg']
]
STRING;

if (preg_match_all("~\s*\['([^']*)',\s*'([^']*)']~", $string, $out, PREG_SET_ORDER)) {
    foreach ($out as $row) {
        var_export($row);     // to demonstrate what is generated
        $image = $row[1];     // for your actual usage
        $thumbnail = $row[2]; // for your actual usage
        echo "\n---\n";
    }
}
```

Output:

```
array (
  0 => '  [\'https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/615JCt72MXL._UY575_.jpg\', \'https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/41rExpVS75L._US40_.jpg\']',
  1 => 'https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/615JCt72MXL._UY575_.jpg',
  2 => 'https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/41rExpVS75L._US40_.jpg',
)
---
array (
  0 => '  [\'https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/71Ss5tJW-4L._UY575_.jpg\', \'https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/41RpAwvZJ5L._US40_.jpg\']',
  1 => 'https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/71Ss5tJW-4L._UY575_.jpg',
  2 => 'https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/41RpAwvZJ5L._US40_.jpg',
)
---
array (
  0 => '  [\'https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/6157znz2BeL._UY575_.jpg\', \'https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/41mSje9rDSL._US40_.jpg\']',
  1 => 'https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/6157znz2BeL._UY575_.jpg',
  2 => 'https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/41mSje9rDSL._US40_.jpg',
)
---
array (
  0 => '  [\'https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/815wlLde-gL._UY575_.jpg\', \'https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/51jty5d4BpL._US40_.jpg\']',
  1 => 'https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/815wlLde-gL._UY575_.jpg',
  2 => 'https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/51jty5d4BpL._US40_.jpg',
)
---
array (
  0 => '  [\'https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/71D2gVlCUOL._UY575_.jpg\', \'https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/41kCBJYI%2BCL._US40_.jpg\']',
  1 => 'https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/71D2gVlCUOL._UY575_.jpg',
  2 => 'https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/41kCBJYI%2BCL._US40_.jpg',
)
---
array (
  0 => '  [\'https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/71EfsMWdx0L._UY575_.jpg\', \'https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/41utl4%2B%2B%2BoL._US40_.jpg\']',
  1 => 'https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/71EfsMWdx0L._UY575_.jpg',
  2 => 'https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/41utl4%2B%2B%2BoL._US40_.jpg',
)
---
array (
  0 => '  [\'https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/61m4mFpIvVL._UY575_.jpg\', \'https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/41S27BGn0UL._US40_.jpg\']',
  1 => 'https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/61m4mFpIvVL._UY575_.jpg',
  2 => 'https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/41S27BGn0UL._US40_.jpg',
)
---
```

Comment: @Anthony Too complicated?  Need me to explain anything further?

Comment: @Anthony I got the impression from your comment that you were seeking a cleaner, more direct solution.

Comment: exploding it twice was sufficient, but very useful answer nonetheless. if i run into issues, ill def try your solution!